# How to parse this format?

Tags: php, serialization

I'm trying to parse a string which looks like this : 
`"['x','y','z',['a'],[],[['name','2'],['name','40']]]"`

I would like to put everythings in an array like this :

```
 0 => string 'x' (length=1)
  1 => string 'y' (length=1)
  2 => string 'z' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'name' (length=4)
          1 => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'name' (length=4)
          1 => string '40' (length=2)
```

Is there a proper way to do it because I tried to make a bunch of functions, but at the end it's always a mess and it doesn't work.

Comment: If you replace the `'`'s with `"`'s, then you have a JSON string and can `json_decode()` it.

Comment: Thanks you, I knew I could use json_decode however, it didn't work because of the " at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: Bulk replacing quotes like that is only going to work until you get data that actually contains a quote, at which point it'll either fail to decode, or break the data. You need to either fix what is producing that nonsense encoding, or implement the appropriate decoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats nearly a JSON String, so make it into one and from there its easy running

```
$nearlyJson = "['x','y','z',['a'],[],[['name','2'],['name','40']]]";

$nowItsJson = str_replace("'", '"', $nearlyJson );

$NowItsAPHPArray = json_decode($nowItsJson );
print_r($NowItsAPHPArray );
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => x
    [1] => y
    [2] => z
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => name
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => name
                    [1] => 40
                )
        )
)
```